# How get domain from string?

Tags: javascript

`var string = "https://example.com/app/something";
var string = "example.com/app/something";
new URL(string.origin)`

If `string` have protocol all ok, and if not. have error *Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL(…)*

How can I obtain the root domain without using regex?

Comment: `string.origin` is `undefined`. Did you mean `location.origin`? And if you did, why would you ever *not* have a protocol?

Comment: @p.s.w.g I was thinking the same thing, but I believe OP is not getting the URL from the `window.location` object. If that is the case, I don't know of a way to get the URL origin without using a regex.

Comment: `new URL('http://example.com/app/something')` return object if string have http or https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is still a bit unclear, and I'm not entirely sure how you're getting that string, but just for the sake of argument, here's a quick solution:

```js
function getHostname(str)
{
  str = (/^\w+:\/\//.test(str) ? "" : "http://") + str
  return new URL(str).hostname;
}

console.log(getHostname("https://example.com/app/something"));
console.log(getHostname("example.com/app/something"));
```

Yes, technically, this technically does use a regular expression to check if the protocol is present, but it uses the `URL` class actually parse the host name.

Comment: This is a better solution than mine. I didn't even think of using `URL.hostname`, well done!

Answer (score 0):

Regex example:

```js
var example1 = "www.example1.com/test/path";
var example2 = "https://example2.com/test/path";
var example3 = "http://subdomain.example3.com/test/path";

function getDomain(str) {
  var matches = str.match(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?((?:[-A-Za-z0-9]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6})/);
  if (!matches || matches.length < 2) return '';
  return matches[1];
}

console.log(getDomain(example1));
console.log(getDomain(example2));
console.log(getDomain(example3));
```

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match
- http://regexr.com/

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to check if the URL contains either the http or https protocol. This can easily be done with string functions built into JavaScript as shown below.

```
var string = window.location;
if (string.includes('http') || string.includes('https'))
{
    //Do your logic here
}
```

UPDATE: Alternatively, you could use substring functionality shown below.

```
var string = window.location;
if (string.indexOf('http') == 0)
{
    //Do your logic here
}
```

Note that this will also verify that the http is at the beginning of the string and not just thrown in willy nilly.

Comment: Includes is nice, but keep in mind it does not have very good support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Nice catch! I updated the comment with a better version.

Comment: `includes` also won't work if the string is something like `"example.com/http"`. The `indexOf` is a much better solution, but it won't work the string is something like `"http.example.com/app"` (granted, that's not a common scenario).

Comment: I intended the code above to be something that could be built on. The question was so vague on requirements that I made no assumption on how verbose it needed to be.